# Shell program behaves differently when read from a file vs. pipe

Tags: bash

I made a bash script for my personal usage which sets up selenium webdriver with appropriate options . Here is its raw link - https://del.dog/raw/edivamubos

If i execute this script using curl after writing it to a file first like..

```
curl https://del.dog/raw/edivamubos -o test.sh && \
chmod u+x test.sh && \
bash test.sh
```

The script works perfectly as its intended to work

But usually i like to execute scripts directly using curl , so when i do..

```
curl https://del.dog/raw/edivamubos | bash
```

The script works very weirdly , it keeps repeating line 22,23 and 29 infinitely on loop. i couldnt beleive it as first so i tested this 3,4 times and can confirm it.

Now

1. what is the reason for same script acting differently in both cases ?
2. How do i fix it ( ie make it work correctly even after executing it directly without writing to a file )

Edit -
If someone want they can quickly test this in [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/#create=true) ( in case someone intending to test but don't want to install any packages locally ) . I am mentioning this thing because you won't be able to reproduce this properly in any bash IDE.

Comment: Your question should be self-contained and present a [mre]. We should not need to click external links (which often stop working after a while anyway, or worse, lead to sites with undesirable content) to view your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pipe the script to bash, this command (line 24):

```
read -p "Enter your input : " input
```

reads the next line (i.e. line 25, `case $input in`) because bash's stdin is connected to curl's stdout, and `read` reads from the same descriptor as bash.

To avoid that, the developer can change the script so that all input is read from `/dev/tty` (i.e. the controlling terminal). E.g.:

```
read -p 'prompt' input </dev/tty
```

Or the user can use one of the below, so that `read` reads from the terminal, not the descriptor it was read from.

```
bash -c "$(curl link)"
bash <(curl link)
```

Comment: hello sir , i have been using your </dev/tty solution everytime i used read command in bash , it worked great . But i am now getting error - bash: line X: /dev/tty: No such device or address . Is there any alternative or fix for this ? ( developer side fix only ie in script itself , not the user end solutions)

Comment: Sounds like a good question. Why don't you ask it separately?