# Python input being asnwered by shell script

Tags: python, bash, github

I have a shell script that updates my system, installs some packages, etc. I want to run a python program from my shell script. My shell script looks something like this:

```sh
#!bin/bash
sudo python3 /OCMS/src/setup.py
```

And the Python script:

```
print('Question #1')
print('Do X')
print('Do Y')
dl_choice = input('Enter Answer here ')
```

I have the shell script and the python script in github, and when I do

```sh
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/XXX/XXX/master/bashsetup.sh | sudo bash
```

the input gets answered automatically and it errors out with

```
EOFError: EOF When reading a line
```

Comment: A similar question was asked a few weeks ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62609724/why-is-the-bash-script-functioning-differently-if-i-execute-it-directly-and-exec `input()`  reads the next line of bash script. That `curl ... | bash` is a bad practice anyways, stop doing that.

Comment: Is there anything better than piping it into bash?